# Set a buffer/file local variable in elisp like a file local variable

Tags: buffer-local

I'm looking for a way to set a variable that isn't buffer local in such a way that it will act like one.

It's possible to do it with [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables), but I haven't found a way to set a variable in this way from elisp.

I don't want to rely on defining file local variables with comments inside of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set a buffer-local value for a variable, use `setq-local`.

Depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish, you may also want to look at the help for `make-local-variable` and `make-variable-buffer-local`. These functions do not actually set a value, but arrange for a variable to have a buffer-local value when set.

Comment: Neither `make-local-variable` nor `make-variable-buffer-local` "***set[s]** a buffer-local value for a variable.*"